# Activity transition using overrideActivityTransition doesn't work in Android 34

Tags: java, android, android-activity, overridependingtransition

I am using `overridePendingTransition` to make a transition from MainActivity to a Sub-Activity. The transition moves MainActivty out on the right, and the Sub-Activity into the screen from the left.

I need that the transition is triggered by pressing a button and not started by back pressed.

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

After change to `overrideActivityTransition` above transition doesn't work for Android >=34.

```
overrideActivityTransition(OVERRIDE_TRANSITION_OPEN,R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

How can i restore the behaviour under Android 34?

Thanks
GGK

Comment: The same thing happens to me too.

Answer (score 0):

The `overrideActivityTransition` isn't fully compatible with the previous `overridePendingTransition` method.
You should call the `overrideActivityTransition` inside your `Sub-Activity`'s `onCreate()` method:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34) {
    overrideActivityTransition(
        Activity.OVERRIDE_TRANSITION_OPEN,
        R.anim.slide_in_left,
        R.anim.slide_out_right,
        Color.TRANSPARENT
    )
}
```

For further explanation, look at the documentation:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/features/predictive-back#custom-activity

Comment: Thanks, but that is the same thing I am using it for. I need that the transition is triggered by pressing a button and not started by back pressed